Best way to set folder permissions in docker container after every restart?
My cluster gets torn down at the end of every day. It looks like the base mounted folder for my apllication (/ni) has its permissions updated for an owner of local.adm. Instead, I need this to be my-user as the owner and group.
Anyone know of a clean way to do this? Thanks!

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What's in this directory, and why do its permissions matter?  (Should you remove the volume mount entirely?)
